# How to print all the contiguous subarray of the array

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I was working on some algorithm and I wanted to find the contiguous subarray of the array.

For example, if my input array is as below,

```
vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 2, 3, 1}
```

I want to get the ouput vector as below,

```
vector<vector<int>> output;
//Output should contain {1, 2, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 3, 1}, 
//{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1},{1, 2}, {2, 2}, 
//{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {3}, {1}
```

Comment: Generate all the possible index pairs in order w.r.t. length.

Comment: That would definitely solve the issue but I am looking for the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the algorithm, it is shown as below,

```
vector<vector<int>> Solution::sliceArray(vector<int> vect)
{
  vector< vector<int> > listOfVect;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
      vector<int>  indVect(vect.size() -i );
      copy(vect.begin() + j , vect.end() - i + j , indVect.begin());
      listOfVect.push_back(indVect);
    }
  }
  return listOfVect;
}
```